# Laravel Model Not Saving but It Says It Is (Inside of Observer class)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a task model and I am trying to do a simple create to test something in one of my observer classes. Here's my create code.

```
private function generateTasks(Event $event)
{
    $tasks = [];

    $tasks[] = [
        'event_id' => $event->id,
        'title' => 'This is a test',
        'description' => 'this is a description',
        'due_on' => Carbon::now()->addDays(14)
    ];

    dump(Task::all());
    // foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $task = Task::create([
            'event_id' => $event->id,
            'title' => 'This is a test',
            'description' => 'this is a description',
            'due_on' => Carbon::now()->addDays(14)
        ]);

        if ($task->save()) {
            echo "Saved";
        }
        else {
            echo "NO SAVE";
        }

        dump($task);
    // }

    dd($tasks, "DONE");
}
```

And the output is below:

[image]

When I look at the database the table remains at 120 rows. This is really odd because it says it's saving. When I grab all the tasks you can see in the output it has 120 rows. If you look at my latest output id you'll see that I am up to 133.

Any ideas what is going on here?

**UPDATE**:

My fillables:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'description', 'due_on', 'event_id', 'completed'
];
```

Completed has a default of false.

My table looks like this to give you guys an idea:

[image]

Comment: It should be saving, since it has an id. Check the max ID in the table to verify.

Comment: maybe some column is not fillable inside model

Comment: I updated with some more information. Weirdest thing is that it's incrementing but the table stays at 120.

Comment: There's something suspicious here. In the dd of $task, table is empty. Just to try it, add `protected $table = 'tasks';` to your model. Also a silly thing (but something that trips me up with multiple environments), but make sure you're querying the right server and database the environment is using.

Comment: That was a good catch/try, but unfortunately not the solution. It does show 'tasks' instead of null when I added the protected variable but it's still not saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting help from the [laravel chat](https://larachat.co/). Big shout-out to them. The problem was that I was using a dump die inside of a transaction. This was causing what appeared to be a save but then, because the die was called before the transaction commit, it was rolling everything back. It was a silly mistake. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

the create does the save method you do not need to do it again you can do it as the following:

```
 private function generateTasks(Event $event)
{

 $tasks = [];

$tasks[] = [
    'event_id' => $event->id,
    'title' => 'This is a test',
    'description' => 'this is a description',
    'due_on' => Carbon::now()->addDays(14)
];
    $task = Task::create([
        'event_id' => $event->id,
        'title' => 'This is a test',
        'description' => 'this is a description',
        'due_on' => Carbon::now()->addDays(14)
    ]);

    if ($task) {
        echo "Saved";
    }
    else {
        echo "NO SAVE";
    }

dd($tasks, "DONE");
```

}

Comment: I know that, I did that to check if it was saving as a test. It's not saving in either case.

Comment: do you the table name called tasks

Comment: Yes my table is named tasks and my model is named Task.php. This works in other places. It's only in this Observer class.

Comment: do you use    use  App\Task; in your controller

Comment: Yes, I did. use App\Models\Task;

Comment: if you put the task model inside model folder

Comment: check the namespace  must be like this  namespace App\Model;

Comment: Yes, that's not the problem. All of that is correct. It would throw an error if that was the issue. The problem is that it isn't saving.